# curl to cfhttp translation

Tags: php, curl, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to translate a PHP script into ColdFusion and did not succeed. Could somebody help me?

Original PHP script (for unifi wlan manager api):

```html
$unifiServer = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx";
$unifiUser = "xxxxx";
$unifiPass = "xxxxx";

// Start Curl for login
$ch = curl_init();
// We are posting data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// Set up cookies
$cookie_file = "/tmp/unifi_cookie";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
// Allow Self Signed Certs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// Force SSL1 only
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
// Login to the UniFi controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$unifiServer/api/login");
$data = json_encode(array("username" => $unifiUser,"password" => $unifiPass));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
// send login command
curl_exec ($ch);
```

ColdFusion cfhttp translation:

```html
<cfhttp url="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/api/login" method="POST" result="test">
    <cfhttpparam type = "formField" name = "username" value="xxxxxxx">
    <cfhttpparam type = "formField" name = "password" value="xxxxxxxx">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">    
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#test#">
```

cfhttp fails with:

> "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server"
>   msg" : "api.err.Invalid" , "rc"

SSL certificate is installed in cert store.

Comment: Try sending the `username` and `password` in the body of the request instead of `formfield` as, the data would be url encoded and from the php snippet it seems like you need it json encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$unifiUser = "xxxxx";
$unifiPass = "xxxxx";
$data      = json_encode(array("username" => $unifiUser,"password" => $unifiPass));
```

translates to

```
<cfset unifiUser = "xxxxx">
<cfset unifiPass = "xxxxx">
<cfset data      = serializeJSON({ "username" = unifiUser, "password" = unifiPass })>
```

and your curl's payload translates to

```
<cfhttp url="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/api/login" method="POST" result="test">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#data#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#test#">
```

---

To send a cookie:

```
<cfset cookie_file    = "/tmp/unifi_cookie">
<cfset cookie_content = fileRead(cookie_file)>
```

and add

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Cookie" value="#cookie_content#">
```

If you need to send multiple cookies, you have to concatenate them in `cookie_content` using semicolon `;`.

Comment: Great, that works! Thank you very much for the Translation Alex!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I get an cf error "file or directoy /tmp/unifi_Cookie not exists"

Comment: What could be the reson?

Comment: The error tells you: the cookie file doesn't exist. You need to describe where the cookie/information actually comes from. You probably need to store the response of the initial request and use the data for subsequent requests. Please open a new question and describe your workflow in detail.

Comment: I found a solution. When I use

Comment: <cfloop query="test.cookies">
  <cfhttpparam type="COOKIE" name="#test.cookies.name#" value="#test.cookies.value#" />
</cfloop>

Answer (score 0):

if CFHTTP is giving you headaches (which it often does when dealing with SSL/HTTPS), consider instead calling CURL from your command line, using CFEXECUTE.

For example:

```
<cfexecute timeout="10" name="curl" variable="myVar" arguments="https://google.com"></cfexecute>
```